# Как установить JAXB в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, javafx, jaxb

Заменил JDK в текущем javafx проекте (НЕ мавен) с 8 на 9, т.к. понадобилась фича, которой нет в 8 (java.awt.Desktop browseFileDirectory()). 
И в проекте "потерялась" функция JAXB Маршаллинга. 
Полез искать - скачал внешнюю библиотеку на сайте https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2

Но скачанные файлы не распознаются Идеей. Импорты JAXB в проекте выделены красным и не работают.
Как быть? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если хотите использовать Java 9, придётся [разобраться с модулями](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/support-for-java-9-modules-in-intellij-idea-2017-1/).

Comment: Спасибо, а внешнюю библиотеку типа jaxb-ri тоже через эти модули подключать?

Comment: Что-то и вся JavaFX под 9 исчезла, хотя в структуре штатных библиотек 9-ки она видна (javafx.base library root и т.д.)... Что ж делать-то???

Comment: JavaFX, как и JAXB, всё ещё в составе стандартной библиотеки, но оформлена в отдельный модуль. В следующих версиях Java этому подвергнуться все пакеты стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Это уже понял – под 11 javafx не получилось установить. А есть ли где-то внятное руководство, как пользоваться импортом модулей в 9? Завел файл module-info.java, прописал импорты-экспорты, протыкал везде, где просила идея – в итоге импорты засорены какими перекрестными упоминаниями одних и тех же своих же классов, а аппликация перестала грузиться нормально (открывает пустое окно, а далее, видимо, FXML не загружается...)

Comment: Я таких не знаю. Разве что гуглить по запросам "java jigsaw", "java 9 modules" и "java 9 modularity", а потом читать всю выдачу до просветления.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы! В итоге  просто завел пустой проект под sdk 9, завел там все классы заново, скопипастил код (без импортов, чтобы само отработало импорты заново), и все в итоге заработало. JAXB всосало через мавен-импорт модулей.